# JavaScript: Calling Array.reduce when outer function is called, and outer function has arguments

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

```
var foo = 0;
var bar = 0;
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function getSum(arr, sum) {
    sum = arr.reduce(function(accum, val) {
      return accum += val;
    }, 0)
}

getSum(arr1, foo); //expect foo to equal 15, but it stays at 0
getSum(arr2, bar); //expect bar to equal 40, but it stays at 0
```

I'd like to use this function multiple times, hence the arguments. I know having the `sum` argument equal `Array.reduce()` isn't what you're supposed to do, but I'm really not sure what the syntax should be.

Basically I want `arr1` values to always be added up for `foo`, and `arr2` always added up for `bar`, without having to repeat my code.

Comment: You're not returning anything from `getSum`, it should be `undefined`, not 0. You also do not have `data` anywhere in your code. Fix that to `arr`, and it works as expected.

Comment: If you want to provide an initial argument to `reduce`, pass it as the second parameter (instead of using 0)

Comment: You can't pass a variable into a function like this and expect to assign a value back to that variable. You need to return the value from the function and assign that returned variable to the function: `foo = getSum(arr)`

Comment: the `sum` arg get passed by value, not by reference.  this is because `sum` is a primitive type (`Number`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, primitive types are passed by value.  Objects are passed by reference.  You *can* accomplish this by wrapping `foo` up in an object, but you really should not design code this way.  Code that mutates function arguments is often very hard to reason about (and debug).

```js
var foo = { value: 0 };
var bar = { value: 0 };
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    
function getSum(arr, sum) {
    sum.value = arr.reduce(function(accum, val) {
      return accum += val;
    }, 0)
}
    
getSum(arr1, foo);
getSum(arr2, bar);

console.log(foo.value);
console.log(bar.value);
```

If possible, you should try to find a way to solve your problem without mutation.

In fact, many linting tools (like eslint) will throw an error if they see function arguments being mutated.

Instead, you should separate the `sum` function from the assignment of the resulting value:

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
        
function sum(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(acc, next) { return acc + next });
}

var foo = sum(arr1);
var bar = sum(arr2);
    
console.log(foo);
console.log(bar);
```

Comment: The second snippet, with `arr.reduce` being returned seems to work. I thought I always had to assign a value to `Array.reduce()`, but doing it where I just return the method is working. Thanks.

Comment: @00Saad if no initial value is supplied to `reduce` it uses the first value of the array as the initial value.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you just need a sum function like this:

```js
var foo = 0;
var bar = 0;
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const getSum = (arr) => arr.reduce((r,c) => r+c)

foo = getSum(arr1)
bar = getSum(arr2)
 
console.log(foo)
console.log(bar)
```

Comment: First part of your answer is perfect. Second part is absolute nonesense. `foo` and `bar` won't be assigned anything. They will always have `0` as value

Comment: Yeah wrong test there. Good point!

Comment: One more tiny note: IMHO, It is preferable to use a regular function instead of an arrow one for consistency reasons (OP may not be familiar with arrow functions syntax, so he may not be able to see the improvement your answer provide over his code).